# Составить SQL запрос

Tags: mysql

Определить максимальное количество сотрудников работавших когда-либо

одновременно.

Таблицы

**DEPT**

COLUMN NAME  |  TYPE       |    COMMENT

DEPTNO       | CHAR(3)     |    Код подразделения

PARENT_DEPTNO| CHAR(3)     |    Родительское подразделение

DEPTNAME     |VARCHAR2(100)|    Наименование подразделения

**EMP**

COLUMN NAME TYPE            COMMENT

EMPNO           CHAR(5)         Код сотрудника

DEPTNO          CHAR(3)         Подразделение сотрудника

HIRE_DATE   DATE            Дата приёма на работу

FIRE_DATE   DATE            Дата увольнения

FIRSTNAME       VARCHAR2(200)   Имя

LASTNAME    VARCHAR2(200)   Фамилия

POSITION    VARCHAR2(100)   Должность

MGR         CHAR(5)         Руководитель

Comment: Вам не кажется что Вам нужно хоть предложить структуру таблиц?

Comment: да конечно вы правы

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под "одновременно" ?Какой промежуток времени можно считать "одновременно"?

Comment: Мне эти ссылки помогли.Надеюсь они Вам помогут
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901886/group-by-time-to-a-24-hour-day
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896785/mysql-get-records-from-last-7-days
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793994/group-mysql-query-by-15-min-intervals